# Optimizing a function with multiple outputs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

Say I have a function

`[f,g,h] = function (x)`

In the file `function.m` in Matlab. How can I find the value `x`, e.g. using `fminunc`, which maximizes `g`? The `fminunc` documentation only handles the case when the objective function returns a single value.

Comment: What exactly do you want to find, the minimum of `function`?

Comment: I'm looking for x* = min_x h(x).

Comment: What is `h`, could you show what exactly `function` does?

Comment: If you don't use variables f and h. You can create a mimic function which call your function inside which passes the argument x to it and returns g only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *must* provide `fminunc` with a function that returns a scalar, so in your case you'll just have to declare a helper function that returns `g`:

```
g = function helper_func(x)
    [f, g, h] = func(x);
```

and feed the helper function into `fminunc`:

```
x = fminunc(@helper_func, x0);
```

Comment: Are there any guidelines on how to combine multiple goals into a single scalar?  How to weight conflicting goals, etc.